# Microsoft Excel some Data Points on Diagram are wrong (X-Axis)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a problem with a diagram in excel.

As you can see on the image, the data point I hovered over with the mouse shows that it is the point with an X-Value of "1.99" - which is roughly where all the curves should end. But only two of them do. (The Y-Values are fine).

[image: Illustration of the excel Problem]

The data is generated by a vb-script, which works fine; The display of them is my only problem.

I have tried several diagram types already, it happens no matter if I only use dots or lines or a pie.

I have also tried formatting the cells where the data come from, to no result. Also I tried formatting the X-Axis but that didnt yield a result either.

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016 to generate this but the Problem also exists on an installation of Excel 2013.

Comment: Please provide the data you have graphed, or the code you have used to create the data.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Shame on me. I used the wrong Diagram Type; had to change to XY Scatter / Lines.